# Get Visual Studio Code to look locally when no path is supplied

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a statement like this:

```
var {ShipmentValidation} = require('ShipmentValidation');
```

In most projects I work on, I think this means look in my NPM packages for ShipmentValidation. (I usually use `'./ShipmentValidation'` to indicate I need to look locally.)

But I am working on a project now (TestComplete) where I need the "no path" option to look in the local folder for the file.  (Because I can't change how TestComplete works.)

**Is it possible to configure VS Code to look for "non-path requires" in the local folder (same folder as the current file)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to make a file called `jsconfig.json` and put this in it:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      // This must be specified if "paths" is set
      "baseUrl": "."      
    }
}
```